# Centering audio in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: mac, audio, final-cut-pro, sound-volume

I'm currently working in Final cut pro on a little project. I have a stereo audio file that has two mics and when one person speaks it plays in one cup of my headphones and when the other speaks it plays in the other cup. Is there a way to "center" this audio so it plays out of both cups rather than just the one?

Comment: See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAfU0tkjrAg

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have a stereo project (timeline), unless you are dealing with 5.1 (surround) files:

[image]

Select the clip, and at the property inspector set it to dual mono:

[image]

Now both tracks will play at both channels.
By doing that you will also enable breaking apart clip itens (command+shift+G):

[image]

Tracks are now independent from the video.

[image]

You can manually map each one for whatever speaker you want.

[image]

Just remember you can't break apart all the channels before setting them to mono. If they are grouped you will just detach it from the video.

Also, expanding the audio tracks (option+control+s) won't do pretty much anything regarding channels, it is just a tool for visual aid and some editing purposes.